# disable UITableView offscreen rendering

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, layout

I am using a full-height UITableView (basically tableView.height = tableView.contentSize.height) and this tableView is in a scrollview meaning that it overflow of the screen.

Here's a picture that may be more explicit:

[image: view]

Everything is scrolling fine and smoothly but since the table height is equal to its contentSize all the cells are being rendered immediately which cause massive lags when the controller appears.

So I am wondering if there is a way to prevent offscreen cell rendering or if there is a better way to implement this view ?

Thank you.

Comment: could you tell us what exactly you are trying to make... may be real screenshot will help us...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tableView height issue huge, you should set view 1 and view 2 as a cell from section 0 ( and keep your content in section 1 ).

You don't need your scrollview anymore